# Simple jquery Slider with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a image slider with some css animation but I can not figure out the part where i need to add and remove my css class 
basically i need to add the css animation class to the h1 when the imagelisder is completely loaded, remove it when the next slide is about to be shown , add it again to the next slider

here is the code

```js
'use strict';

$(function() {

    //settings for slider
    var width = 720;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 6000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    //cache DOM elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
    var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
     $('h1').addClass('sliderCaption');
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
                $('h1').removeClass('sliderCaption');
            });
        }, pause);
    }
    function pauseSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    $slideContainer
        .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
        .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

    startSlider();


});
```

```css
#slider {
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider .slide {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.sliderCaption{
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -150px;
 animation: mymove 5s ease;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: -150px;}
    to {left: 0px;}
}

/* helper css, since we don't have images */
.slide1 {background: red;}
.slide2 {background: blue;}
.slide3 {background: green;}
.slide4 {background: purple;}
.slide5 {background: pink;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <h3 class="text-muted">jQuery Basic Slider</h3>
 </div>

 <div id="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
   <li class="slide slide1">
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
   </li>
   <li class="slide slide2"><h1>Some Text</h1></li>
   <li class="slide slide3">slide3</li>
   <li class="slide slide4">slide4</li>
   <li class="slide slide5">slide5</li>
   <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks